# Why spring is unable to load beans from the xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a web application, which is based on Spring MVC. I am trying to load Bean definition from a XML using following code snippet;

```
final AbstractApplicationContext fileContext2 =
                    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-integration-context_webinf.xml")
```

But this does not work. File is located in WEB-INF directory, which I assume must be on classpath. If I import the file using @import resources -it works.

I am not stuck on this, but curious why its not working!

Comment: do you get something like "Resource not found" ?

Comment: consider learning instead of assuming.  WEB-INF is not on the classpath.  This is obvious because it is not getting loaded.  Try putting the file on the classpath, perhaps in WEB-INF/classes.  If you are using Maven (and the answers is either "no, I'm dumb" or "yes, I am using Maven") put the file in the src/main/resources directory and it will go to the correct place on build.

Comment: Or use `org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext` to load the context from WEB-INF. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153136/why-does-the-classpath-default-to-the-web-inf-classes-instead-of-web-inf-in-jb).

Comment: If the file is in the `WEB-INF` it isn't on the classpath, nor should you be loading it like that. As you are creating a web application (why else would you have a `WEB-INF`) either the `COntextLoaderListener` or `DispatcherServlet` should be used. Never load it manually...